# Office 365 Public Website JavaScript Snippets - how to remove

Tags: javascript, css, custom-masterpage

Playing around with Office 365 public website Master Page.  Used security trimming to strip down the master page to reduce weight for use in responsive design.  Assumption is we would not want any of the MS scripts on the page (still need a few to make Web Forms work).

Does anyone know where this comes from / how to remove it?  Assuming a delegate control?

```
(function (){

                if (document.getElementById('ms-belltown-table'))
                {
                    var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
                    var content = document.querySelector('.contentwrapper');

                    if (footer && content) {
                        content.style.marginBottom = footer.clientHeight + 'px';
                    }

                } else if (document.all && document.querySelector && !document.addEventListener) 
                {
                    var titleRow = document.getElementById('titlerow');
                    var contentRow = document.getElementById('contentrow');
                    var footerRow = document.getElementById('DeltaPlaceHolderFooter');

                    if (titleRow && contentRow && footerRow) {
                        titleRow.style.height = titleRow.clientHeight + 'px';
                        contentRow.style.height = 'auto';
                        footerRow.style.height = footerRow.clientHeight + 'px';
                    };
                };

            }());
```

Search is registering a few scripts even when search has been turned off.

Navigation is registering a few scripts as well - however we have that turned off as well.

Scripts are not in the master page so must be in a delegate control.

Example Markup: http://spgoo-public.sharepoint.com/directions

Any thoughts on how to further trim this down would be appreciated!